# C++ Class usage in another class

Tags: c++

I have two classes:

One is class A which has a method called Plus and adds two values.

In class B I use the class A and do something. Now I don't know how

should I use class A in class B. Is there only extending? Or there are other methods? How

should it be instanciated?

```
Class A 
{
public :

  int Plus(int a, int b)
  {
    return (a + b);
  }
}
```

The following class is the main class from which an instance of class A should be made:

```
Class B
{
public :

  int Show(string Item, int a, int b)
  {

      cout << Item << A->Plus(a, b) << endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: *Which* diagram? There is none in your question.

Comment: Wowww...sorry, i just was not aware of that topic, I edited that. Bad mistake.

Comment: You haven't said why you need class A at all. It doesn't look like you do.

Comment: I need that, this is simplified version of another situation.

Comment: It depends on what `A` is and what its lifetime is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't clearly understand what do you mean by saying "should I use", but you can modify code:

```
class A 
{
public :

  int Plus(int a, int b)
  {
    return (a + b);
  }
};

class B: public A
{
public :

  int Show(string Item, int a, int b)
  {

      cout << Item << A::Plus(a, b) << endl;
  }
};
```

Or you can try to make `static int Plus()`